# Importing table from mutiple urls to create single dataframe and csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Importing tables from multiple URLs and wanting to create a single data frame to then store as a csv file. I am struggling to delete the repeating description from the tables and I am unable to manipulate the data frame *dfmaster* after creation.

Maybe `pd.read_html` is importing as a list and not data frame?

I have tried to iterate through the incoming table and using;

```
for item in df:  
        if item not in dfmaster:            
            dfmaster.append(item)   
            print(dfmaster)
```

But this seems to list the offending repeated row.

I have also tried `drop.duplicates` after appending to *dfmaster* and `df.drop[0]`

```
producturls = ['https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=2222&exch=ecbot&showcategories=FUTGRP',
               'https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=2222&exch=cfe&showcategories=FUTGRP',
               'https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=2222&exch=dtb&showcategories=FUTGRP&p=&cc=&limit=100&page=2'
               ]
dfmaster =[]

for url in producturls: 
    table = pd.read_html(url, index_col=None, header=None,)
    df = table[2]

    for item in df:  
        if item not in dfmaster:            
            dfmaster.append(item)   
            print(dfmaster)

    dfmaster.to_csv('IB_tickers.csv')
```

Output should stitch all table data from websites into one data frame without repeating the description header and then create and store as a readable csv file.

Thank you so much for taking a look.

Comment: How did you define `dfmaster`?

Comment: you can concatenate an arbitrary number of dataframes (contained in a list) using pandas.concat.  see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html  so loop through the list of urls, append each dataframe into a list, and then use pandas.concat to combine into a single dataframe.  Then export that dataframe to csv

Comment: Do I need to define the dfmaster?? Should I add dfmaster=pd.DataFrame

Comment: Ian thank you, but is that not what my code is doing ? pd.read_html returns a dataframe and I appending it to dfmaster. The code creates an object but its not in a dataframe.

Comment: *dfmaster* is a list not a data frame. @Ian is advising `true_df = pd.concat(dfmaster)`. Then export to csv: `true_df.to_csv('file.csv')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import  tabulate

producturls = ['https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=2222&exch=ecbot&showcategories=FUTGRP',
               'https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=2222&exch=cfe&showcategories=FUTGRP',
               'https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=2222&exch=dtb&showcategories=FUTGRP&p=&cc=&limit=100&page=2'
               ]

df_list = []

for url in producturls:
    table = pd.read_html(url, index_col=None, header=None,)
    df = table[2]
    df_list.append(df)

dfmaster = pd.concat(df_list, sort=False)
dfmaster = dfmaster.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print(tabulate(dfmaster.head(), headers='keys'))
dfmaster.to_csv('IB_tickers.csv')
```

Result:

```
    IB Symbol    Product Description                                      Symbol    Currency
                                         (click link for more details)
--  -----------  -------------------------------------------------------  --------  ----------
 0  AC           Ethanol -CME                                             EH        USD
 1  AIGCI        Bloomberg Commodity Index                                AW        USD
 2  B1U          30-Year Deliverable Interest Rate Swap Futures           B1U       USD
 3  DJUSRE       Dow Jones US Real Estate Index                           RX        USD
 4  F1U          5-Year Deliverable Interest Rate Swap Futures            F1U       USD
```

Comment: Ian I have been trying all day and I feel guilty taking you and your solution for granted. Thank  you so much this worked, just needed to install tabulate. Thank you, a million times over !

Comment: @yan365 You did all the hard work already.  Tabulate is such a handy package for visualizing dataframes.  Take care!