# Creating a single dataframe from multiple urls in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm currently trying to push data from multiple urls into a single dataframe which i then want to export to an excel file. I have been trying a method I found on here but it doesn't do the trick for me:

```
Import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
from tabulate import tabulate
final_date = today.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

power_data = ['https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/scheduledCommercialExchangesDayAhead/show'
              '?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BORDER_CTY&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime'
              '='+final_date+'+00:00|CET|DAY&border.values=CTY|10YFR-RTE------C!CTY_CTY|10YFR-RTE------C_CTY_CTY'
                             '|10YBE----------2&direction.values=Export&direction.values=Import&dateTime.timezone'
                             '=CET_CEST&dateTime.timezone_input=CET+(UTC+1)+/+CEST+(UTC+2)','https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/scheduledCommercialExchangesDayAhead/show?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BORDER_CTY&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime='+final_date+'+00:00|CET|DAY&border.values=CTY|10YFR-RTE------C!CTY_CTY|10YFR-RTE------C_CTY_CTY|10Y1001A1001A83F&direction.values=Export&direction.values=Import&dateTime.timezone=CET_CEST&dateTime.timezone_input=CET+(UTC+1)+/+CEST+(UTC+2)']
df_list = []
for url in power_data:
table = pd.read_html(url, index_col=None, header=None,)
df = table
df_list.append(df)
df_final = pd.concat(df_list, sort=False)
df_final = df_final.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print(tabulate(df_final.head(), headers='keys'))
df_final.to_excel('power_data.xlsx')
```

Doing this gives me the error: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

How do I circumvent this error?

Comment: This may helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59544302/typeerror-cannot-concatenate-object-of-type-class-str-only-series-and-da

Comment: "trying a method I found on here" link the post so we can see

Comment: I used this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823821/importing-table-from-mutiple-urls-to-create-single-dataframe-and-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  I just tweaked it a bit...

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
from tabulate import tabulate

today = date.today()
final_date = today.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

power_data = ['https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/scheduledCommercialExchangesDayAhead/show'
              '?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BORDER_CTY&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime'
              '='+final_date+'+00:00|CET|DAY&border.values=CTY|10YFR-RTE------C!CTY_CTY|10YFR-RTE------C_CTY_CTY'
                             '|10YBE----------2&direction.values=Export&direction.values=Import&dateTime.timezone'
                             '=CET_CEST&dateTime.timezone_input=CET+(UTC+1)+/+CEST+(UTC+2)','https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/scheduledCommercialExchangesDayAhead/show?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BORDER_CTY&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime='+final_date+'+00:00|CET|DAY&border.values=CTY|10YFR-RTE------C!CTY_CTY|10YFR-RTE------C_CTY_CTY|10Y1001A1001A83F&direction.values=Export&direction.values=Import&dateTime.timezone=CET_CEST&dateTime.timezone_input=CET+(UTC+1)+/+CEST+(UTC+2)']
df_list = []
for url in power_data:
    tables = pd.read_html(url, index_col=None, header=None,)
    df = tables[0]
    df_list.append(df)
    
df_final = pd.concat(df_list, sort=False)
df_final = df_final.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print(tabulate(df_final.head(), headers='keys'))
df_final.to_excel('power_data.xlsx')

df_final
```

[image]